# Rebasing all unmerged commits

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I often find myself willing to rebase (interactively) all commits of my current working branch that are not merged to master. How do I accomplish this?

A solution based solely on git commands/parameters is preferred (I use git on both Linux with Bash and Windows with PowerShell).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git rebase` selects commits that aren't merged into the target branch that you specify so this does what you need.

```
git rebase -i master
```

Inferring from your other answer, if you want to retain the original root you can do the following, although it may have "interesting" conflicts if you have any interleaved merges from master.

```
git rebase -i $(git merge-base HEAD master)
```